# How can I resolve OutofMemoryError error? (After Bitmap.createScaledBitmap)

Tags: android, out-of-memory, image-resizing, scaletype

I know, there are a lot of similar questions in Stackoverflow. But I could not solve my problem.

I have some kind of jigsaw puzzle. The pictures in the Drawable-nodpi folder are 2500x1250.

I am trying to resize the images with the following code suggested:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;


        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

I call it like this:
(I call these codes several times.)

```
private Bitmap resizeImg (int rsm) {

    Bitmap bmp = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),rsm,wdth,hght);

   return bmp;
}
```

I need to use `Matrix` as the scaling of Imageview. But it's not the size I want. It works right without the `Matrix`.

I'm solving the `Matrix` problem like this:

> Bitmap.createScaledBitmap

```
private Bitmap resizeImg (int rsm) {

    Bitmap bmp = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),rsm,wdth,hght);

   //  return bmp;

    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, wdth,hght,true); //I get OutOfMemoryError this line.
    return resized;

}
```

This insertion really solves my problem. But every day I get lots of OutOfMemoryError errors.

What do I need to do to fix this error? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Try getting rid of the first `decodeResource()` call, with the `inJustDecodeBounds = true`. You know the size of the images, as you provided that detail in the question. I don't know how well `inJustDecodeBounds = true` works with resources, and since you already know the size, it would save time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1] Add largeHeap as true in android manifest to your application tag:

```
          android:largeHeap="true"
```

2] Recycle your all used bitmaps,

```
    Example:
         bmp.recycle();
         resized.recycle();
```

Comment: I'm already using `android:largeHeap="true"`. I will try the other codes and write the result. Thank you.

Comment: but be sure, you are not using Bitmap instance after called recycle(), else your will get exception "trying to use a recycled bitmap" & app will get crash.

Comment: Yes. I arranged the codes by paying attention to this. The application is up to date on the market. There are fewer mistakes than before. But the error still exists. I do not get any errors on my test devices myself.